# Windows RSVP QoS service is stopped when no QoS-socket active. Can that be changed?

Tags: winsock2, qos

We have a program that uses QoS-sockets, our softphone application uses QoS for the RTP.

That application is normally left running, sometimes however it is restarted. (Stop, wait 300ms, start.)

We have found that when the softphone-application is stopped that the last one useing QoS on the server, so the RSVP QoS-service on windows is stopped as well.

When we restart our application the RSCP QoS-service normally starts really fast, however sometimes the service start takes a full 30 seconds, causing our application to start slowly as well.

Anyone know if I can configure the service not to stop each time?

The computer is Windows XP SP3, with Windows Firewall turned on. (Our application do have  an exception in the firewall.)

Regards
Leif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this was solved with a workaround.

In the main-application we now open a QoS-socket, which we keep open until the main-application ends. That way the RSVP service cannot be closed, since it's in use.
(I found that opening the socket without bind()-ing works, so we don't need any port.)